# Can't shrink C: partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, bitlocker

Before any of you close this **read it**. No other solutions on this site have worked for me.

I need to shrink the partition of my C: drive on Windows 10, but am having trouble. I think it could be because it's encrypted with Bitlocker. Can I shrink the volume while it's encrypted, or do I have to decrypt first?

And if so, how? I can't shrink this partition at all and have tried multiple different things.

One of the main solutions that seems to fix it is using the AOMEI Partition Assistant, but it doesn't even seem to be detecting that anything is even in the partition (when there is, of course)
[image]

I think the most likely cause is the pagefile. However, I can't turn it off - it always just automatically switches to "system managed"

Update: I got rid of the pagefile, but still can't shrink the partition using Disk Management *or* AOMEI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before shrinking this partition you need to decrypt it. There is currently no tool to shrink an encrypted partition. So: decrypt, shrink, eventually once again encrypt.